# How to link to my root_path plus an anchor using HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this snippet of code using haml

```
%li.tab.col.s3.l2
  %a{:href => "#main_kpis"} KPIs
 #main_kpis.col.s12.no-padding
  .col.s12.light-sky-grid
    #kpis_wrapper
```

When I click on the li>tab element, I go directly to the div main_kpis, but I need to send the full URL to the browser.... How can I do that?

Comment: The full URL to what? The current page?

Comment: Yes, to the same page, I just need the link adds he anchor to the url..

Answer (score 0):

```
%li.tab.col.s3.l2
  = link_to("KPIs", root_url(anchor: '#main_kpis'))
  #main_kpis.col.s12.no-padding
    .col.s12.light-sky-grid
      #kpis_wrapper
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell there are some paths after the root url and they need to be honored when clicked on the link.......127.0.0.1/acess/dashboard/currentpage?params.....

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html